# How do I create my own custom ToString() format?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I would like to specify the format of the `ToString` format, but I am not sure of the best way to handle this.

For example if I have the following specifiers

- EE = equipment
- ED = equipment description
- EI = equipment ID

so that if I used the `ToString` as such:

```
eqp.ToString("EE-EI (ED)")
```

the output might be:

```
"CAT994-61 (Front end loader)"
```

Would the best way be to search for the substrings and do a token replacement?
 Does any one have an example of doing this?

I'm currently doing sequential `string.Replace`, which works nicely.

```
public class Equipment
{
    // (other class code)

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        string output = format;
        output = output.Replace("EE", _EquipID);
        output = output.Replace("ED", _EquipDescription);
        output = output.Replace("DI", _DepartID);
        return output;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _EquipID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Combining string format, and overloading the `ToString` you can do this:

```
public override string ToString(string myFormat)
{
    myFormat = myFormat.Replace("EE", "{0}");
    myFormat = myFormat.Replace("EI", "{1}");
    myFormat = myFormat.Replace("ED", "{2}");
    return String.Format(myFormat, this.equipment, this.description, this.id);
}
```

You can also use regular expressions to make the `Replace` functions nicer.

---

This can be used as follows:

```
oProd.ToString("EE,ED,EI");
oProd.ToString("EE-ED (EI)"); // change order
oProd.ToString("ED-EE,EE,EE (EI)"); // multiple times
oProd.ToString("ED:EI"); // have some missing
etc
```

The String.Format gives you the flexibility to position the format variables any way like, have them multiple times, or drop some.

Comment: the string.format() method, does it not decrease the flexability, see my above edit. I did use your answer, but I wasn't sure of the point on the string.format()

Answer (score 6):

First override ToString()

Then if you want it to be dynamic you would have to parse the format string a token at a time and add the appropriate string to your output string. Using single letter format specifiers would make it a little simpler since you could parse it a character at a time. If it is a special character you output the appropriate data else output the character.

So something like this

```
public override string ToString(string format)
{
  StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (char c in format)
  {
    switch (c)
    {
      case 'E':
        s.Append(EquipID);
        break;
      case 'D':
        s.Append(EquipDesc);
        break;
      case 'I':
        s.Append(DepartID);
        break;
      default:
        s.Append(c);
        break;
    }
  }

  return s.ToString();
}
```

This has the relatively minor advantage of doing it in one pass which is more efficient than multiple string replace calls.

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Format("{0:foo}", object);
```

Will end up passing `"foo"` to `object.ToString(string format);` so it makes sense to design the arguments that your `ToString(string format)` method takes with that in mind. In your example

```
String.Format("{0:EI - EE}", object);
```

would result in "EI - EE" being passed to the ToString method on object, so this could work as you describe, but it might make more sense to restrict the format to one representation at a time, like this

```
String.Format("{0:EI} - {0:EE}", object);
```

would be the way to get "CAT994-61" as output, and your ToString() method could be simpler

```
public override string ToString(string myFormat)
{
    string str = null;
    switch (myformat.ToLower())
    {
       case "ee": str = this.equipment; break;
       case "ei": str = this.description; break;
       case "ed": str = this.id; break;
       default: str = this.ToString(); break;
    }
    return str;
}
```

If you reduce your format specifiers to single letters, that would be more consistent with the way other objects handle ToString formats.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format`.

```
String.Format("{0}-{1} ({2})", "CAT994", 61, "Front end loader");
```

produces the expected output.

Comment: so if I mixed the tokens up like ToString("EI - EE") it would still work?

Comment: `String.Format("{1}-{0} ({2})", "Foo", "Bar", "Baz");` results in `"Bar-Foo (Baz)"`.

Answer (score 0):

The format sounds like a good solution.
Perhaps a (few) nice regular expression(s) to cut your input variable into groups.

I would try to use as many existing formats if you can:
http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score -1):

You just need to overload the ToString function in your object like

```
public override string ToString()
{
    /* some code handling here */
    return ""; //your own formated string
}
```